# Using STOMP Java Client to reach a spring endpoint

Tags: java, stomp

I want to establish a `STOMP` connection between my server and a java test client. The destination of the websocket would be something like `localhost:1234/data/websocket/`.

None of the java stomp implementations seem to support such an address format. Is there a way to create a STOMP connection to such an endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use the Spring `STOMP` client. It was the only client I found, which was able to connect to such a specific endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look to this documentation : [**Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

> ### Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application
>
> This guide walks you through the process of creating a "hello world"
>   application that sends messages back and forth, between a browser and
>   the server. WebSocket is a very thin, lightweight layer above TCP. It
>   makes it very suitable to use "subprotocols" to embed messages. In
>   this guide we’ll dive in and use **[STOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol)** messaging with Spring
>   to create an interactive web application.